# Replace multiple patterns by start and end index in R

Tags: r, string, replace, gsub

```
mystring <- c("code IS (384333)\n   AND parse = TURE \n ) \n 
              \n code IS (43343344)\n ) some information here
              code IS (23423422) ) and more information")
```

I have a string where I want to replace characters from index 1-40 with "orange" and characters from index 61-81 with "blue".

**1. Attempt with `gsubfn`**

```
library(gsubfn)
toreplace <- list(replace1 = "orange", replace2 = "blue")
names(toreplace) <- c(substr(mystring, 1, 40), substr(mystring, 61, 81))
```

I got the following error:

```
> gsubfn(paste(names(toreplace), collapse = "|"), toreplace, mystring)
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] couldn't compile regular expression pattern: parentheses () not balanced.
```

**2. Attempt with `gsub`:**

```
pat = paste(c(substr(mystring, 1, 40), substr(mystring, 61, 81)), collapse='|')
replace = paste("orange", "blue", collapse = "|")
> gsub(pat, replace, mystring)
[1] "code IS (384333)\n   AND parse = TURE \n ) \n \n              \n code IS (43343344)\n ) some information here\n              code IS (23423422) ) and more information"
```

But I did not get the desired output. In fact, it didn't seem to have replaced anything.

The desired output is

```
"orange \n 
              \n blue some information here
              code IS (23423422) ) and more information"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a nested `sub`.

```r
sub(substr(mystring, 1, 40), "orange", 
    sub(substr(mystring, 61, 81), "blue", mystring, fixed = T), fixed = T)
[1] "orange \n \n              \n blue some information here\n              code IS (23423422) ) and more information"
```